# How would I make it so this box can be minimized and maximized?

Tags: javascript, css

```
#you {
    background-color: rgba(65,64,61,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 200px;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    width: 165px;
    border: 2px solid #41403d;
 }
 #exitb { 
    background: url(http://playneko.co.uk/exit.png);
    height: 19px;
    width: 19px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
#exitb:hover {
    background: url(http://playneko.co.uk/exit_hover.png);
}
```

Thats my css code andd this is the box I have

```
<div id="you">
    <div style="height: 110px; width: 57px; float: left; overflow: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure='.$user['look'].'&direction=3&head_direction=3&action=wav,crr=667&size=m" alt="avatar" class="rotate" align="left">
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; z-index:1">'.$aanwezag.'</div>
    <br/>
    </td>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:10px;left:65px;font-size:18px;font-family: Times;">%habboName%</div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:30px;left:65px;font-size:18px;font-family: Times;">' . $users->getRankName($user['rank']) . '</div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:50px;left:65px;font-size:18px;font-family: Times;"><font color="#FF0040">'. $user['age'] .' Years Old</font></div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:70px;left:65px;font-size:18px;font-family: Times;"><font color="#088A4B">'. $user2['AchievementScore'] .' Score</font></div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:90px;left:65px;font-size:18px;font-family: Times;"><font color="#01A9DB">'. $user2['Respect'] .' Respects</font></div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:81px;left:5px;font-size:20px;font-family: Times;"><img src="%www%/flags/'. $user['country'] .'.png"></div>
</div>
```

How would I add the exit image on the right of the box to be able to minimize and maximise the box? if you can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post us the output HTML instead of the PHP?

Comment: What the exact problem? Have you tried anything by yourself? Could you please make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Marc what do you mean by the html output and I tried editing one on jsfiddle but it just got rid of the box completely

Comment: heres the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qy6Sj/1598/

Comment: You would want to use something more like jQueries animate function.. That way you would animate the height of the div to something like the height of the button.. This wont make it vanish, if you want it to move to the bottom of the page.. Well then this is another concept in itself.. You could use an absolute position, but use jquery to find the bottom of the page and offset it.

Comment: would you be able to make it work within this code http://pastebin.com/Q6VyuTZM

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have to wrap a content which should toggle into a separate `div` and toggle this `div` instead of whole `#you` element

```
<div id="you">
    <div id="exitb">-</div>
    <div id=content>
        ...
    </div>
</div>


$("#content").slideToggle();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Qy6Sj/1602/

Comment: Nope. Please try it by yourself and then ask about a concrete problem which you will be faced with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you wanted or not. I have moved the `#exitb` id out of the `#you` wrapper and positioned it as `absolute` as well in order to move it into the image. Moreover, I simplified the code a little bit to use just a text, `+` and `-`, instead of image icons.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="exitb">-</div>
<div id="you">
    ...
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#exitb").click(function () {
    if ($(this).html() == "-") {
        $(this).html("+");
    } else {
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $("#you").slideToggle();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#exitb {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
    height:19px;
    width:19px;
    border-radius:3px;
    cursor: point;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:200px;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qy6Sj/1603/).

Comment: I have it like that but where do I add the javascript because this is what I have my code looking like currently http://pastebin.com/JAMfXLBY